# How to access position of an element relative to its parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to get the position of an element relative to its parent element. So for this i am using jquery `position function` I created a [JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wwzUd/3/)

In this fiddle i am accessing the `top & left` position of `#child` element. It should return `top : 0 and left : 0` because it is the children of `#p` element and its position is relative but it is returning `top : 223px and left : 1px`. Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the tweak
The problem was you did not specify the parent's position as relative. So the child position was calculated with respect to body

```
<style type="text/css">
#gp {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:gray;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#p {
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#child{
    position: relative;
}
</style>

<div id="gp">
 <div id="p">
     <div id="child">
     </div>
 </div>
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert($("#child").position().top + " " + $("#child").position().left);
});
```

Comment: If you don't want to change your CSS architecture, take a look at mine !

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this :

```
function relative_pos(node) {
  var parentOf = $(node).parent().offset();
  var child = $(node).offset();
  return {top: child.top - parentOf.top, left: child.left - parentOf.left};
}

console.log(relative_pos("#child"));
```

[Try !!!](http://jsfiddle.net/wwzUd/7/)